# Angular/PrimeNG: How to use ng-template within p-radiobutton

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to show a question mark icon when sponsrtype.id == 2 however my ng-template seems to not work. Any idea what is wrong with what i am doing below?

```
    <span *ngFor="let sponsorType of sponsorTypes; let i = index">
    <p-radioButton name="sponsorType" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="sponsorType.id" [label]="sponsorType.description"  [(ngModel)]="selectedSponsor.sponsorTypeId">
                            <ng-template let-sponsor pTemplate="item">
                                <i  class="fa fa-question-circle" *ngIf="sponsor.id == 2"  aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <a class="infoLink smallTxt" >What is apples?</a>
                              </ng-template>
</p-radioButton>
</span>
```

Comment: Templating does not apply for `p-radioButton` according to PrimeNG doc.

Comment: So any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't use `ng-template` inside `p-radioButton`, you can do something like :

```
 <span *ngFor="let sponsorType of sponsorTypes; let i = index">
    <p-radioButton name="sponsorType" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="sponsorType.id" [label]="sponsorType.description"  [(ngModel)]="selectedSponsor.sponsorTypeId"></p-radioButton>
    <span *ngIf="sponsorType.id == 2">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <a class="infoLink smallTxt" >What is apples?</a>
    </span>
</span>
```